# app has stopped working, but log doesn't show error?

Tags: android

i am trying to test one app page but it keeps crashing. however, the logcat doesn't show me an error, unlike the other questions on stackoverflow. I have no clue what is wrong, and i would really appreciate it if someone could point out the error for me. 
I know i have unfinished code in the main, but i'm not executing any of them, so i thought it was okay.

here is the log file

```
       ??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.230  2347: 2347 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.230  2347: 2347 W/linker   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.270  2347: 2347 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): CheckJNI is ON
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.360  2347: 2347 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.370  2347: 2347 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.400  2347: 2347 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.400  2347: 2347 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.400  2347: 2347 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:49.670  2347: 2347 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:50.400  2347: 2347 E/memtrack ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:50.400  2347: 2347 E/android.os.Debug ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): failed to load memtrack module: -2
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:50.740  2347: 2347 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:50.790  2347: 2347 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Shutting down VM
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:50.800  2347: 2354 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.550  2358: 2358 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.550  2358: 2358 W/linker   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.600  2358: 2358 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): CheckJNI is ON
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.690  2358: 2358 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.690  2358: 2358 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.720  2358: 2358 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.720  2358: 2358 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.720  2358: 2358 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:51.990  2358: 2358 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:52.640  2358: 2358 E/memtrack ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:52.640  2358: 2358 E/android.os.Debug ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): failed to load memtrack module: -2
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.180  2358: 2358 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.300  1269: 1434 I/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.safety/.MainActivity} from pid 2358
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.480   923:  923 D/gralloc  ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/SurfaceFlinger ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1043711944
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/SurfaceFlinger ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.490   923:  923 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.530  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.530  1269: 1434 W/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21005
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.730  2358: 2358 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Shutting down VM
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.740  2358: 2365 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.860  1269: 1315 I/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Start proc com.example.safety for activity com.example.safety/.MainActivity: pid=2374 uid=10052 gids={50052}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.880  1269: 1284 I/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Killing 1472:com.android.music/u0a32 (adj 15): empty for 1808s
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.910  1269: 1284 I/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Killing 1415:com.android.printspooler/u0a39 (adj 15): empty for 1809s
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:53.950  1269: 1431 W/MediaFocusControl ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):   RemoteControlClient died
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:54.060  2374: 2374 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:54.400  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:55.020  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 314 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:55.570  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 346 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:55.960  2374: 2374 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Shutting down VM
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:56.000  2374: 2374 W/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1d79b20)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:56.080  2374: 2374 E/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Process: com.example.safety, PID: 2374
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.safety/com.example.safety.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class Layout
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class Layout
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.safety.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     ... 11 more
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.safety-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.safety-2, /system/lib]]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     ... 24 more
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:56.340  1269: 1570 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):   Force finishing activity com.example.safety/.MainActivity
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:56.690  1269: 1570 I/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b2388600 ActivityRecord{b22931f8 u0 com.example.safety/.MainActivity t10 f}} appWin=Window{b23ac578 u0 Starting com.example.safety} drawState=4
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:56.690  1269: 1570 W/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (320x480) to layer 21010
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:56.910  1269: 1284 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:57.150  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:57.210  1269: 1284 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b22931f8 u0 com.example.safety/.MainActivity t10 f}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:57.340  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 10-02 22:09:57.540  1269: 1283 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

i checked to see if the package/activity name is the same in my main.xml and it looks like the same

```
package com.example.safety;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        EditText newDestination;
        EditText newLocation;
//      newDestination= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newD);
//      newLocation= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newLoc);


        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id==R.id.goBackButton) {
            //go back to enter locatoin page
        }

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html");

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

there also is the default activity launch in manifest (and i only have one activity right now)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
</manifest>
```

here is my activity page in case you need to see that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBackButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="@string/returnToStart" />

    <Layout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/estimatedTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/goBackButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/goBackButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="@string/chosenRouteTime"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/goBackButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/goBackButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/estimatedTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mapDescriptor"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/map" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your LogCat and not the Console.

Comment: okay, i will do that
sorry, logcat or logcat deprecated ?

Comment: ok, logcat posted. it seems really long though

Comment: Your problem is the `<Layout>` element in the layout xml. There is no View with that name in the SDK. Perhaps you want a LinearLayout, or RelativeLayout, or some such instead?

Comment: thank you for your help :D 
i took it out, and rerunning now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Layout` is not a valid tag in the Android SDK, so your app is crashing when it tries to create your interface defined in the XML file.

Try changing out the `Layout` on line 16 of your XML file for something else, whichever is appropriate from this list: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts

You can create your own by subclassing `ViewGroup`, as well, if you wish - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: thanks for your response :)
do i need to replace it with something else ?
i'm not even sure why there's a layout tag in my file

Comment: If you don't need it then there's no reason for it to be there. I thought you'd put it in there and mistakenly given it the wrong tag . Notably, it's always a good idea to keep your layouts as shallow as possible. More nested `Views` mean overdrawing, resulting in an inefficient app.

Comment: sorry, one more question. the thing i am testing is supposed to show a webpage, but that isn't popping up. would you happen to know why not ?

Comment: You have the code that does the loading of the webpage in a strange place, do you want the page to be loaded every time someone chooses an option from the options menu or a specific option?

Comment: i haven't made the other pages yet, but there's supposed to be a page where people enter a location and a destination, and then pick out of a list of route options. after one route is picked then the current page in my code should load, and i always want to see the webpage view.