# Not able to imort package.R in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {

        fullLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer, null);

        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        if (useToolbar()) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        } else {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        setUpNavView();
    }
```

The above code gives me a error as layout not found. I have google and found that I need to import package.R. But I am not able to import package.R.

[image]

The image show the layout file in package. Still not able to find the layout while using **getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer, null);**

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_base"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Error
                                                                     **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.handyandy.handyandy-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]**

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: No solution with clean and rebuild

Comment: Please find the xml file

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like your issue is most likely concerning the use of the v4.DrawerLayout. These features aren't part of the standard SDK, so make sure you have downloaded the relevant libraries and installed them properly (plenty of docs on this on the Developer site). This StackOverflow answer might help you once you've done that too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172234/app-has-stopped-working-but-log-doesnt-show-error